# React Context not updating value to pass to another page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

I am creating an ecommerce app with `Nextjs` and want to share data between pages. I know that we can't use `props` to pass data between the pages and so was looking into react `context` api. This is my first time using react context api. I've researched and found that you should add the Provider in the _app.js page in nextjs.
But this shares the data among all the pages. Plus my data is being retrieved by `getStaticProps` in the slug page of the app. I want to get this data into the checkout page of my app.

This is the context I have created:

```
import { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react';

const productContext = createContext({} as any);

export const ProductProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [productData, setProductData] = useState('');
  return <productontext.Provider value={{ productData, setProductData }}>{children}</productContext.Provider>;
};

export const useProduct = () => useContext(productContext);
```

_app.js

```
import { ReportProvider } from '../contexts/ReportContext';
export default function CustomApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
  
            <ReportProvider>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </ReportProvider>
          
  );
}
```

I import this into the slug page and try to update the state from here

```
// [slug].js

import client from '../../client'
import {useProduct} from './productContext';

const Post = (props) => {
  const {setProductData} = useProduct();
  const { title = 'Missing title', name = 'Missing name' , price} = props
  setProductData(title);
  return (
    <article>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <span>By {name}</span>
      <button>
           <a href="/checkout">Buy Now</a>
     </button>
    </article>
  )
}

Post.getInitialProps = async function(context) {
  const { slug = "" } = context.query
  return await client.fetch(`
    *[_type == "post" && slug.current == $slug][0]{title, "name": author->name, price}
  `, { slug })
}

export default Post
```

However this productData is not accessible from another page and the react context state is not getting updated.
Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Did you used the provider into your `_app.js` file?

Comment: Yes I did. Ill add the _app.js to the above question.

Comment: @SifatHaque What I've noticed is that the state updates on the slug page but when i move to another page the state resets.

Comment: Please make sure your page is not refreshing when you move between pages.

Comment: How do we not make the pages refresh?

Comment: to move between pages you need to use next.js link. You can check this from here. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link

Comment: Yes this worked. Thnx for that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've updated your context value. Please make sure you are using `next/link` to navigate between pages. Here is details about [next/link](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link)